# Running a script against multiple servers, but the outcome is out of order

Tags: powershell

So, I'm using invoke-command to run a script against more than one server simultaneously:

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servers -Credential $Cred -FilePath "C:\RemoteScript.ps1"`

However the results appear to be out of order:

User: username
FQDN: DEVSERVER01.localnet.int
IP: 10.0.0.101

```
Server uptime: 20 days
======================

User: username
FQDN: DEVSERVER02.localnet.int
IP: 10.0.0.202

Server uptime: 20 days
======================

User: username
FQDN: DEVSERVER03.localnet.int
IP: 10.0.0.303

Server uptime: 20 days
======================

List of updates for DEVSERVER01.localnet.int:
No updates

List of updates for DEVSERVER02.localnet.int:
No updates

List of updates for DEVSERVER03.localnet.int:
No updates
```

I also want to log the results for each server but this is what I came up with:

```
Start-Process -FilePath Powershell -ArgumentList "
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -Credential $Cred -FilePath "C:\RemoteScript.ps1"
" -RedirectStandardOutput "$Server Log.txt" -Wait
```

How should I be able to run my script on two servers but should try to get the results from each server in order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, when targeting multiple computers in parallel with `Invoke-Command`, the order of the output objects across computers is *not* guaranteed.

You can use [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) to group the output objects by their (implicitly added) `PSComputerName` property, which reflects the computer of origin:

```bash
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servers -Credential $Cred -FilePath C:\RemoteScript.ps1 |
  Group-Object PSComputerName |
  ForEach-Object { Set-Content "$($_.Name) Log.txt" -Value $_.Group }
```

Note that `Group-Object` implicitly and invariably outputs the groups sorted by the grouping criterion/a, so that the groups are sorted by computer name in this case.

*Caveat*: In your case, given that you're writing the results to *files*, you have no expectation of console output anyway, but if you do want to see the results in the console instead, note that `Group-Object` has to collect *all* output, across all computers, before it can display the results.